# Can I summon Blue Eyes Chaos MAX from my deck?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

What if I have Chaos Form in my hand, with the required materials but Chaos MAX is not in my hand. Can I summon it from the main deck?

Answer (score 4):

No you can't.
This simply isn't how ritual summons work. Unless any card states otherwise (e.g. the nekroz ritual spells) you must tribute monsters from your hand or field to summon a ritual monster from your hand.

In general you cannot interact with cards in your main deck, unless another cards specifically states otherwise.

Answer (score -5):

I mean it doesn't really say that you can't. So I guess it's up to players choice?

"thats simply not how ritual summons work" doesn't really apply. The game has evolved so much if it doesn't specifically say that you **can't** summon it from the deck then go for it.

Comment: A quick look at the basic rules for ritual summoning proves this answer incorrect - it's stated that you need the ritual monster in the hand in order to summon it.